# Get Part Of Url In different Cases

Tags: php

I would like to ask from you today if you help me improve my code I'm trying to get the id of the url it's always in the end after /id/ for this example I need "9050102" without quotes.

The url can come in different ways:

```
.site.com/Descreption-Text-Etc/id/9050102
site.com/Descreption-Text-Etc/id/9050102
site.com/bi/product/9050102
.site.com/bi/product/9050102
```

My code:

```
$foo = explode('/', $url); //Extracing ID
$id = strtoupper($foo[3]); //ID
```

I have noticed in some cases it didn't work not sure why
so after that I have added:

```
if (!$id) { 

$id = strtoupper($foo[2]); //Making Sure ID Found

}
```

can you help me improve that to find it 100% accurately and always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function to get the last element in an array. It sets the array pointer to the last element and returns its value.

```
$foo = explode('/', $url); //Extracing ID
$id = strtoupper(end($foo)); //ID
if(isset($id) && strlen($id)==10) {
//code
}
```

Comment: interesting I wasn't aware of end in php. I also want to add a fail safe if the id wasn't set to get a random one how to know if $id is emtpy?

Comment: this will work if it's empty right? Can I ask for one small improvement? What if $id is set but not what I need. Lets verify if $id is 10 character alphanumeric long? if not I will set it manually

Comment: `if(isset($id) && $id && (strlen($id) === 10) {
//code
}` is this right?

Comment: yes exactly 10 chars if more or less it's not good so should it be == or ===?

Comment: also I don't really understand why we check isset and also $id won't isset will be enough?

Comment: == would be enough in your case. Just to check $id is not empty, it is not necessary since we have added strlen

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the ID will always be on the last position, you can use the `end` function to get the last element of the array:

```
$id = end($foo);

if ($id && isset($id[9])) {
   // this means that the ID exists and has at least 10 characters
}
```

Comment: interesting I wasn't aware of `end` in php. I also want to add a fail safe if the id wasn't set to get a random one how to know if $id is emtpy?

Comment: I just updated the answer to add verification of existence and even more, if the 10th character is present or not.

Comment: thank you for adding the 10 characters. this will mean if it has at least 10 characters right? How can I change that to 10 characters only if less or if more it's not good ;)?

Comment: well, if you want to be 10 chars exactly you are left with using `strlen($id) === 10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = explode('/', $url);
//count the $foo array
$count = count($foo);
//the last index will be minus 1
$id = $foo[$count-1];
```

Comment: how to know if $id is empty? I will specify it manualy if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$url = "site.com/Descreption-Text-Etc/id/9050102";
echo substr($url, strrpos($url, "/") + 1);
```